# Screen flickers after resuming from hibernate with Intel GMA 3600 (Acer D270 with Intel N2600)

Tags: drivers, hardware-failure, hibernate, graphics

Fresh system install, with correct display driver from Intel (8.14.8.1065). Clicking "Update driver" merely results in a message saying the driver was already up-to-date.

After resuming from hibernate the entire screen flickers. This is especially noticeable while using IE9 (which has hardware acceleration enabled by default) on Google maps, in particular while typing in an address in the map search field (the flickering is much worse under these circumstances). Note that sleep worked fine, only hibernate causes this issue. Restarting "fixes" the problem temporarily until the next hibernate-resume.

Aero is enabled. This is on Windows 7 (Pro) 32-bit, on an Acer Aspire One D270-1998, with the Intel N2600 (which has the Intel GMA 3600 built-in).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this related thread: http://forum.xbmc.org/showthread.php?tid=133401&page=3

Installing a later driver (supposedly for desktop graphics but the installation package seems to include the right driver for the GMA 3600 too) fixed the issue for me(!)

In my particular case, I installed [driver 8.14.8.1083](http://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?agr=Y&DwnldID=21690&lang=eng&OSVersion=%0A&DownloadType=). Before installing this driver I uninstalled the old one (via Device Manager), just in case.